# How to do Sub Selects

Tags: linq, nhibernate

given the code ( this is a made up example).  Also imagine Contract and Plan have a bunch more properties on them.

```
class Contract
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set}
   public virtual IList<Plans> {get; set;}
}

class Plan
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set; }
}

var blah = query
    .SelectMany(contract =>
     contract.Plans.Select(plan => new {ContractId = contract.Id, PlanId = plan.Id})
    .ToList();
```

NHibernate will spit the dummy with

```
Cannot create a LambdaExpression that retrieves the value of '[plan]' 
from items with a structure of 'new <>f__AnonymousType168`2(ContractId = 
[contract].Id, PlanId = [plan].Id)'. The item expression does not contain the
 value or it is too complex.
```

If I retrieve a list from the database first with ToList() I can easily do this in Linq to Objects and it gives me what I'm expecting.   Is there a way to do this with Linq and Nhibernate ?

I mainly want to ensure I'm retrieving the minimal necessary from the DB, in my testing by prefetching from the DB then Linq to objects takes ~ a second, the equivalent SQL takes no measurable time

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple. Try this:

```
   (from contract in query.Contracts
    from plan in contract.Plans
    select new
    {
        ContractId = contract.Id,
        PlanId = plan.Id
    })
   .ToList();
```